# Bluetooth stopped working after update from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

It's a Lenovo G580

Output of some commands:

```
$ lsusb | grep "Bluetooth"
Bus 001 Device 033: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0

$ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-11-15 22:33:25 CET; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1291 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1291 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 15 22:33:25 justanother-PC systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 15 22:33:25 justanother-PC bluetoothd[1291]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Nov 15 22:33:25 justanother-PC systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 15 22:33:25 justanother-PC bluetoothd[1291]: Starting SDP server
Nov 15 22:33:25 justanother-PC bluetoothd[1291]: Bluetooth management interface
```

But in settings I see this

[image]

There is no bluetooth switch button on this laptop. Only a functional shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> which switches to flight mode and vise versa. But it not helps too.

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR8162 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31, updated

Comment: That one should work without any issues.  I would file a bug report against package linux, start at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_non-crash_hardware_and_desktop_application_bugs

Comment: Can't reproduce on 18.04 anymore.